# clipspy pendant for pyclips clips.ErrorStream.Read()

Tags: python, clips, clipspy

Is it possible to read the ErrorStream from clips using `clipspy`?
With `pyclips`, it worked this way: `clips.ErrorStream.Read()`.

Does it even make sense to do it with `clipspy`, or are all errors thrown as exceptions and can be caught with `clips.CLIPSError` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `clipspy` detects an error, it raises a `CLIPSError` exception embedding the output of `werror` as message. Therefore, you can mostly rely on that.

Nevertheless, as CLIPS C APIs are not entirely consistent you might find some corner case. Most commonly, the `CLIPSError` exception might not contain any error message as CLIPS does not always print a message in case of error.

If you want to read CLIPS output you can do that by using the routing facilities which are documented in CLIPS `Advanced Programming Guide`. The clipspy [router APIs](https://clipspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clips.html#clips.router.Router) are very close to the C ones.

You can also use the [`LoggingRouter`](https://clipspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clips.html#clips.router.LoggingRouter) to manage CLIPS output with Python logging. This comes handy when you want to integrate CLIPS in a python service.

```
import clips
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

env = clips.Environment()
router = clips.LoggingRouter()

router.add_to_environment(env)

env.eval('(printout t "Hello World!" crlf)')
```

Output

```
2018-10-16 17:29:01,829 - INFO - Hello World!
```